# how to change get php info in htmlB

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to make a product page for various products on my site. So far I don't have any php backend.

my html

```
<div id ="itemsGohere>
//getName() getImageUrl()
//getName() getImageUrl()
//getName() getImageUrl()
</div>
```

The variables I need to call

```
 Var productInfoString = {"images/product1.png" , "ThisProductTitle", "$50"}
```

Can I make a php file to store this information and when a user clicks on product1 it'll load the productInfoString for product1??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to do ajax call on click of a product and send it's id and return the `productInfoString` with a value of that product.